# Flutter ProviderNotFoundException Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I want use Firebase Auth in Flutter project. And I am use `provider`. Everything is okey but I am facing one issue with `provider`.

My IconButtonWidget:

```
class SocialIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String socialIcon;
  const SocialIconButton({Key? key, required this.socialIcon})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: context.dynamicWidth(20)),
      child: IconButton(
          onPressed: (() {
            final provider =
                Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
            provider.login();
          }),
          icon: Image.asset(socialIcon)),
    );
  }
}
```

When I press button I am facing this issue:

```
ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<GoogleSignInProvider> above this SocialIconButton Widget.
```

Comment: did you include provider on main/MaterialApp?

Comment: No, i did not. How should i include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your App with MultiProvider and provide instance like

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GoogleSignInProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

More about [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example). Also you can check riverpod2

Answer (score 0):

Bedfore use provider you need to initialized it in your main.dart file
like this

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
    /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GoogleSignInProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

after that rebuild the app